# regex to grep all numbers after the second-last underscore

Tags: regex

I want to get all the character's after the second last underscore in a string any ideas how this could be accomplished

```
Input                             Output
PART1_PART2_PART3_G2010           PART3_G2010
```

any idea what the regex should look like

Comment: The title is not coherent with the question.. In the title you want all numbers after the last undesrcore, but in the question you want everything that is after the second underscore.. Make up your mind! :)

Comment: No, she said she wants everything after the second last underscore... That is the second counted from the end. Saying that this is the second one counted from the beginning is equivalent in this example, but is wrong for arbitrary inputs.

Comment: If you want to match, but not capture, all the text following the second-to-last underscore you could use `(?<=_)(?=[^_]*_[^_]*$).*`, provided the regex engine supports lookbehinds (here the positive lookbehind `(?<=_)`). Note that if lookbehinds are supported then surely lookaheads (here the positive lookahead `(?=[^_]*_[^_]*$)`) will be supported as well. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pD7Lti/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andrea Spadaccini's answer works if you know that the input has three underscores. If the question was meant more generally, referring to everything after the second underscore independent of how many underscores come before that, the regex needs to search from the end ($) like this:

```
 _([^_]*_[^_]*)$
```

Comment: Can you explain this regex please

Comment: Sure. [^_]* matches any string of non-underscore characters. So the regex matches any string of the form _A_B at the end of the input, where A and B are strings of non-underscore characters. That forces the first underscore in the regex to be the second last underscore in the input. Then the parentheses select everything after that underscore, as you required.

Answer (score 7):

```
.*_([^_]*_[^_]*)$
```

Isn't bound to a specific total count of parts between the underscores, like the regex of Andrea Spadaccini is.

**edit**

The first two symbols `.*` capture every character, cause `.` captures one arbitrary character and `*` is a quantifier for "as much as possible". Then, a underscore should appear.

The expression in brackets should capture the two parts between underscores. Well, at first, we capture all (again the `*`) non-underscore-characters:
This is done using the square brackets and saying we want any character except (`^`) the underscore => `[^_]`. The very last symbol `$` defines the end of the input string. I think it is possible to either leave this OR the `.*` in the beginning out...

Comment: Sorry can you please explain this regex

Comment: The first two symbols `.*` capture every character, cause `.` captures one arbitrary character and `*` is a quantifier for "as much as possible". Then, a underscore should appear. The expression in brackets should capture the two parts between underscores. Well, at first, we capture all (again the *) non-underscore-characters. This is done using the square brackets and saying we want any character except (`^`) the underscore => `[^_]`. The very last symbol `$` defines the end of the input string. I think it is possible to either leave this OR the `.*` in the beginning out...

Comment: added comment into answer, because it's such a great explanation. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

First N not-underscores, than an underscore. Repeat. Group the last characters.

```
[^_]*_[^_]*_(.*)
```

Comment: This captures everything after the second underscore counted from the beginning. In the example this is equivalent, but for arbitrary inputs it isn't.