# how to extract a certain digit from a String using regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex

I have a String (filename): `s_113_2.3gp`

How can I extract the number that appears after the second underscore? In this case it's '`2`' but in some cases that can be a few digits number.

Also the number of digits that appears after the first underscore can vary so the length of this String is not constant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex to grep all numbers after the last underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900070/regex-to-grep-all-numbers-after-the-last-underscore)

Comment: No need for regex: `echo (int)substr("s_113_2.3gp", strrpos("s_113_2.3gp", "_")+1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a capturing group:

```
preg_match('/_(\d+)\.\w+$/', $str, $matches);
$number = $matches[1];
```

`\d+` represents 1 or more digits. The parentheses around that capture it, so you can later retrieve it with `$matches[1]`. The `.` needs to be escaped, because otherwise it would match any character but line breaks. `\w+` matches 1 or more word characters (digits, letters, underscores). And finally the `$` represents the end of the string and "anchors" the regular expression (otherwise you would get problems with strings containing multiple `.`).

This also allows for arbitrary file extensions.

As Ωmega pointed out below there is another possibility, that does not use a capturing group. With the concept of lookarounds, you can avoid matching `_` at the start and the `\.\w+$` at the end:

```
preg_match('/(?<=_)\d+(?=\.\w+$)/', $str, $matches);
$number = $matches[0];
```

However, I would recommend profiling, before applying this rather small optimization. But it is something to keep in mind (or rather, to read up on!).

Comment: You mean using lookbehinds and lookaheads instead? It's a bit of a premature optimization to answer such a basic problem, I would think.

Comment: Your solution is okay, that's why you have no downvotes. But you can do better, and yes with lookarounds...

Answer (score 2):

Using regex lookaround it is very short code:

```
$n = preg_match('/(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)/', $str, $m) ? $m[0] : "";
```

...which reads: find one or more digits `\d+` that are between underscore `(?<=_)` and period `(?=\.)`

Comment: You should probably add the file extension, as well. Otherwise files like `test_4.s_113_2.3gp` will match `4` instead of `2`. (Or at least point out the caveat)

Comment: @m.buettner `/(?<=_)\d+(?=\.[^.]+$)/`